# How to properly send a automatic facebook notification with PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

i want to notify my users for actions made in my application automatically (without choosing the recipient as he is already known).

i use this call as seen in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#requests using php code

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<fb user id to notify>/apprequests?message='<message>'&data='<data>'&access_token=<access token>&method=post
```

all i get is:

```
{
   "request": "22755723071160",
   "to": [
      "<fb user id to notify>"
   ]
}
```

but user cannot see anything. So no error or anything. Where is the notification? Is there any permission to see it properly?

Comment: I found out that the request is delivered to my app center > requests ( https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests ). My intention is to sent it to his facebook notification icon on top. Is this impossible cause of not fair use? Everything i get in my facebook profile is always when a user selected me in a dialog?

Comment: You're referring to Notifications, not Requests. It's not possible to send a notification to a friend that has not added the app themselves. From the docs: 'You use the Notifications API to send these messages to any user who has authorized your app.' https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/

Comment: for friends those have not authorize your app you can post to their timeline as new feed.

Comment: For those who downvote; My intention is not to spam users but to notify them for actions their friends do and they are related. Thank you for your time though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up,

it is not possible to send a notification to a friend of a user who has authorized an application. Only an app request which is send to app center>requests https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests.

Only if the user selects a friend from the dialog (javascript) can send an actual notification!